# Pandas if any value is greater than x subtract x with multiple dataframes different column names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am processing 20 or so data frames each with different column names and in each dataframe, if there is a numeric value greater than x, I want to subtract x.

for example, in df one

```
  Name             ID           DOB
Joe Smith    10000000021021   01011901
Jane Smith   10000001074600   07025901
```

but then in df two I may have

```
Group            Office         OrderNum
20151        10000000060021     20051568
70386            90021          20051568
```

and these column names are different in each df but if a numeric value is greater than 10000000000000, then subtract that amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `applymap`:

```
THRESH = 10000000000000
df.applymap(lambda x: x-THRESH if isinstance(x, (int, float)) and x>THRESH else x)
```

example output:

```
       Name       ID      DOB
Joe   Smith    21021  1011901
Jane  Smith  1074600  7025901
```

Comment: If you have columns with single types and a lot of data, you might want to test @HenryYik approach as well, it might be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select_dtypes` and work on those columns:

```
num = 1e13
dfs = [df1, df2]

for i in dfs:
    cols = i.select_dtypes("int64").columns # or use 'number'
    i[cols] = i[cols].mask(i[cols]>num, i[cols]-num)
    print (i)

         Name       ID      DOB
0   Joe Smith    21021  1011901
1  Jane Smith  1074600  7025901

   Group  Office  OrderNum
0  20151   60021  20051568
1  70386   90021  20051568
```

Comment: That won't work though if a column has a mix of numbers and other (actually I thought it was the case in the question, I realize now I had an hallucination :p)

Comment: Yeah but in that case you would have to first cast each individual value to `int` as well in order to check, which I doubt is OP's case. Could be wrong though.